# finding all numbers $a,b$ that divide $c$ but product of $a$ and $b$ does not divide $c$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Let $a,b,c\in \mathbb{Z}$, such that $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, and both $a$ and $b$ divide $c$. Prove that in this case $ab$ divides $c$. Find all numbers such that $a$ and $b$ divide $c$ but $ab$ does not.

I proved the first part easily. For the second part, is the answer that any two $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$ which are not relatively prime, their product will not divide $c$?

Comment: Not quite as easy, $6$ and $9$ both divide $108$, as does their product. Look at the multiplicities of a prime $p$ in the factorisations of $a,b$, and $c$.

Answer (score 4):

> For the second part, is the answer that any two $a, b\in \mathbb{Z}$ which are not relatively prime, their product will not divide $c$?

Not exactly. For example, take $a = b = 2$ and $c = 4$.

---

However, what you *can* say is the following:

> Let $a, b \in \Bbb Z$ be non-coprime. Then, there exists *some* $c \in \Bbb Z$ such that $a$ and $b$ both divide $c$ but $ab$ does not.

Note that there exists *some* $c$. Your earlier phrasing made it sound like it is true for all $c$ that is a multiple of $a$ and $b$ both.

Now, to prove that claim, we simply find a $c$. You can verify that
$$c = \dfrac{ab}{\gcd(a, b)}$$
does the job.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. How did you come up with $c$? Is it because $c=\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)$?

Comment: Admittedly, I didn't even realise that what I wrote is the lcm. The intuition in my mind was that $ab$ wouldn't divide $c$ when there's some "overlap" in the factors of $a$ and $b$. With this construction, I've have removed the extra factors from $ab$ while still maintaining it to be divisible by both $a$ and $b$. I don't think I'm doing a good job explaining my idea, Daniel Fischer's comment throws more light on how you could've constructed it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the answer but I have an example that disproves your answer to the second part.

Let a = 3, b = 6 and c = 18.

18 = 0 mod 3

18 = 0 mod 6

18 = 0 mod 18

3, 6 are not relatively prime; but their product still divides 18.