# When does $a\mid c$ and $b\mid c$ imply $ab\mid c$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

For example, 
$$2\mid12,3\mid12,6\mid12$$
But,
$$4\mid12,6\mid12,24 \nmid 12$$
When does it work?

Comment: Hint: check the $\gcd$ of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3709495/finding-all-numbers-a-b-that-divide-c-but-product-of-a-and-b-does-not-di/3709507?noredirect=1#comment7623638_3709507

Comment: @mwt , you mean that it works only if gdc(a,b)=1? I.e a and b have to be coprime?

Comment: That's sufficient, but not necessary. In general, we need that $\gcd(a,b)^2 \mid c$.

Comment: $c$ is composite, and can be written $c=abN$ where $N$ is some other number

Comment: @mwt, Any proof?

Comment: For a proof see this site, i.e., [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3709495/finding-all-numbers-a-b-that-divide-c-but-product-of-a-and-b-does-not-di?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: $gcd(a,b)^2$ divides $ab$. So if $ab|c$ then $gcd(a,b)^2$ divides c. This is proof of necessity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proposition you are searching for is valid if $gcd(a,b)=1.$ 
So it goes like this:
 $a|c$ and $b|c$ and $gcd(a,b)=1 \Rightarrow ab/c$

---

Hence, $a$ and $b$ should be relatively prime to achieve the needed result. The counterexample you mentioned did not satisfy the proposition because gcd(6,4)=2. 
**Note**: If you are interested in proving it, go ahead and try using the Bezout Identity!